# store listener not able to load another store extjs 4

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

forum member

I am doing a task in which the Store load another store from inside it. Actually I need the data from another store.

I am having assignmentStore as

```
Ext.define('gantt.store.assignmentStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

        model : 'gantt.model.Assignment',
        autoLoad : true,

        // Must pass a reference to resource store
        resourceStore : Ext.create('gantt.store.resourceStore'),
        proxy : {
            method: 'GET',
            type : 'ajax',
            api: {
                read : 'projectmanagement/data/assignmentdata.js'//,
                //create : 'foo.js',
                //update : 'foo.js',
                //destroy : 'foo.js'
            },
            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                root : 'assignments'
            }
        },
        listeners : {
            load : function() {
                this.resourceStore.loadData(this.proxy.reader.jsonData.resources);
            }
        }
});
```

and my resourceStore is

```
Ext.define('gantt.store.resourceStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.JsonStore',
    model   : 'gantt.model.Resource'    
});
```

**my assignmentData value is**

```
{
    "assignments" : [
        {
            "Id" : 1,
            "TaskId" : 4,
            "ResourceId" : 1,
            "Units" : 100
        },
        {
            "Id" : 2,
            "TaskId" : 4,
            "ResourceId" : 2,
            "Units" : 80
        },
        {
            "Id" : 3,
            "TaskId" : 11,
            "ResourceId" : 5,
            "Units" : 50
        },
        {
            "Id" : 4,
            "TaskId" : 12,
            "ResourceId" : 6,
            "Units" : 50
        }
    ],

    "resources" : [
        {"Id" : 1, "Name" : "Mats" },
        {"Id" : 2, "Name" : "Nickolay" },
        {"Id" : 3, "Name" : "Goran" },
        {"Id" : 4, "Name" : "Dan" },
        {"Id" : 5, "Name" : "Jake" },
        {"Id" : 6, "Name" : "Kim" },
        {"Id" : 7, "Name" : "Bart" }
    ]
}
```

**my resourcePanel code is below**

```
Ext.define('CustomAssignmentCellEditor', {
    extend : "Gnt.widget.AssignmentCellEditor",

    show: function(){
        console.log('SHOW ', this.resourceStore.getCount());

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.define('gantt.view.resourcemgt.resourcePanel',{
    extend: 'Gnt.panel.Gantt',
    alias: 'widget.resourcepanel',

    requires: [
        'Gnt.panel.Gantt',
        'Sch.plugin.TreeCellEditing',
        'Gnt.column.PercentDone',
        'Gnt.column.StartDate',
        'Gnt.column.EndDate',
        'Gnt.widget.AssignmentCellEditor',
        'Gnt.column.ResourceAssignment',
        'Gnt.model.Assignment'
    ],

    height : 400,
    width: 1000,
    multiSelect : true,
    highlightWeekends : true,
    showTodayLine : true,
    loadMask : true,
    enableDependencyDragDrop : false,
    snapToIncrement : true,

    startDate : new Date(2010,0,11), 
    endDate : Sch.util.Date.add(new Date(2010,0,11), Sch.util.Date.WEEK, 20), 
    viewPreset : 'weekAndDayLetter',

        // Object with editor and dataIndex defined
        leftLabelField : {
        dataIndex : 'Name',
        editor : { xtype : 'textfield' }
    },

    // ... or an object with editor and renderer defined
    rightLabelField : {
        dataIndex : 'Id',
        renderer : function(value, record) {
        return 'Id: #' + value;
    }
    },


    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        var resourceStore = Ext.create('gantt.store.resourceStore');
        var assignmentStore = Ext.create('gantt.store.assignmentStore');
        var taskStore = Ext.create('gantt.store.taskStore');

         var assignmentEditor = Ext.create('CustomAssignmentCellEditor', {
                assignmentStore : assignmentStore,
                resourceStore : resourceStore
            });

        Ext.apply(me, {
                resourceStore : resourceStore,
                assignmentStore : assignmentStore,
                taskStore : taskStore,
                stripeRows : true,

                plugins: [
                            Ext.create('Sch.plugin.TreeCellEditing', { 
                                 clicksToEdit: 1
                             })
                          ],

            eventRenderer : function(task) {
                if (assignmentStore.findExact('TaskId', task.data.Id) >= 0) {
                    // This task has resources assigned, show a little icon
                    return {
                        ctcls : 'resources-assigned'
                    };
                }
            },

         // Setup your static columns
            columns : [
                {
                    xtype : 'treecolumn',
                    header : 'Tasks', 
                    dataIndex : 'Name', 
                    width:250
                },
                {
                    header : 'Assigned Resources', 
                    width:150, 
                    editor : assignmentEditor,
                    xtype : 'resourceassigmentcolumn'
                }
            ],

            tbar : [
                    {
                        text : 'Indent',
                        iconCls : 'indent',
                        handler : function() {
                            var sm = g.lockedGrid.getSelectionModel();
                            sm.selected.each(function(t) {
                                t.indent();
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text : 'Outdent',
                        iconCls : 'outdent',
                        handler : function() {
                            var sm = g.lockedGrid.getSelectionModel();
                            sm.selected.each(function(t) {
                                t.outdent();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);

    }
});
```

**my Resource model is**

```
Ext.define('gantt.model.Resource', {
    extend : 'Gnt.model.Resource'
});
```

Actually in my application I am having the grid which displays all the data from AssignmentStore and grid had one column with selection drop down, whose data comes from the ResourceStore.

So I did work with the previous code, but the ResourceStore is not loading so my drop down selection box shows me empty drop down.

Please suggest me some solution I can try to solve it out.

Comment: can you provide a data sample for this: this.proxy.reader.jsonData.resources  and what the Resource model looks like>

Comment: @DmitryB I had updated my question added assignmentData

Comment: Can you add also grid code? It would be easier. Try also to load data in `datachange` handler instead of `load`.

Comment: @Lolo I had updated my question add the grid code containing **resourcePanel** Please help me to find out what here I am doing wrong and solve it as soon as possible.

Comment: If you add trace for this inside you load handler: this.proxy.reader.jsonData.resources - what do you get?

Comment: does 'gantt.model.Resource' Model have a proxy defined or is it fields only?

Comment: @DmitryB not the **gantt.model.Resource** don't have the proxy defined in it . look in my question I had added Resource model.  I think that **assignmentEditor** didn't load the store. Actually initially the data is shown as the **assignmentStore** load the data successfully. But when the grid column is clicked then **assignmentEditor** not able to load proxy as there is not any proxy declaration in it. So do you had any solution how can I declare **assigmentEditor** in my **resourcePanel** so it can be loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your 2nd store loaded with data from the first store load event, which answers the question you asked:  http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/bQvyg/5/embedded/result/

What's happening with your combobox is not clear to me. You need to break down your code into smaller piece so you can understand whats happening.  Your model objects extend other model objects so I cant tell anything about them. Same goes to the panels - they extend custom components not part of ExtJS. You should really be asking Bryntum for advice. I assume it's their scheduler you are trying to extend.

Comment: @DmirtyB you are all correct with this. I am able to display the resource based on assignment, but the problem is that when I click the resource column it is not able to load data from the resourcestore as the proxy is not specified there. In the above example the assignment and resource both comes from the same store, but what will happen if I click the resource column, it has no proxy as specified in my question above. So can you please guide me that instead of using one store how can I use two store assigment and resource so they can display data perfectly

Comment: are you talking about sorting? If so just have it sort locally, if you need a proxy for some reason you can go ahead and add the config, but I don't see why you would need it.

Comment: no I am not talking about sorting. Actually I am talking about **assignmentEditor**. Actually when the grid is clicked the assignmentEditor is not able to load the resources. I had already provided the code of it in **resourcepanel** please have a look to it. thanks

Comment: sorry I don't think I can help you. The editor is a custom component whose code or API I cannot see. There is too much code and difficult to wade through. It's easier if there is a small runnable code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: thanks DmirtyB I got the solution I had made the changes with the below code
**var assignmentStore = Ext.create('gantt.store.assignmentStore');    var resourceStore = assignmentStore.resourceStore;**